# How to delete devices from my device list on apple developer console on device register date

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store-connect

I want to reset my device list from apple developer console because it has exceeded the limit. As per docs, one can only reset the list on the membership renewal day. Today is my device reset date but i cant find an option to reset my device list. From where can i do this?

i have already check my device reset date from membership tab in apple developer console. Later i checked devices section from certificates,Ids and Profiles section but there is no option to perform this action

i expect there should be an option to do it somewhere but i cant find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced same issue in my developer account. I mailed to Apple support and it came with a reply. He had reset all device which was in my account. It will help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Devices and click **Get Started**

[image]

Uncheck the devices which you want to remove and click on **Reset**

[image]

Comment: I am not getting this "Get Started" option. Dont know why. Anyways thanks @Nikunj for your time

Comment: @k_dev Please check you **Your Roles** in View Account page if your team admin did not give to access then you can't do it.